# Reading 0 when reading SMMUv2 registers from user space in Linux

Tags: linux, arm, iommu

There is an ARM SMMUv2 in system, and I want to read its memory mapped registers from Linux user space.
So I opened and mmap `/dev/mem`, the offset is the physical address of SMMU_BASE got from DTS, e.g. 0x8000000.  But when I read from the mmaped region all I got is 0.

There must be something wrong, I also tried with `dd if=/dev/mem of=test bs=4096 skip=32768 count=4`, but it failed with `Bad Address`.
Then I tried in kernel space with `ioremap(0x8000000, 0x1000)`, all I got is also 0.

So what should I do with it?
The user space code is as follows,

```
static int smmuread(int fd, unsigned long address, unsigned int length, off_t offset,
    unsigned long data, unsigned int data_size)
{
    volatile uint8_t *mptr = 0;
    volatile uint8_t *wptr = NULL;
    unsigned int range_len = (length - offset);

    mptr = mmap(0, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, address);
    if (mptr == (void *) -1) {
        printf("Failed to do mmap\n");
        return 1;
    }

    wptr = mptr + offset;
        switch (data_size) {
            case 1:
                printf("%02x\n", *wptr);;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("%04x\n", *(uint16_t *)wptr);;
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("%08x\n", *(uint32_t *)wptr);;
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("%lx\n", *(uint64_t *)wptr);;
                break;
            default:
                range_len = (length - offset);
                if (data_size)
                    range_len = MIN(range_len, data_size);
                dump_range(wptr, range_len);
                break;
        }

    munmap(mptr, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found this is my fault by reading SMMU memory mapped registers in byte.
ARM SMMUv2 spec says

> The SMMU architecture supports atomic register access at the size of
> the register. Whether atomic register accesses  of other sizes are
> supported is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED

So it must use 32bit/64bit read or write.